# Cors Issue in Angulaar 11 with HttpClient

Tags: angular11

this is my service file code.

```
 getSearchValue() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer Key[enter image description here][1]',
    });

    let options = { headers: headers };
    
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl, options)
  }
```

//this is my service file code.
i have fetch the data using online api showing the cors issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's very few cases were you should manually add any CORS related headers when making a request to a server. All of the `Access-Control-Allow-*` prefixed headers you've added to your request are actually response headers that should be returned by the server.